# Anaconda won't open and I'm getting CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 error

Tags: python, error-handling, anaconda, conda

I'm currently having problems with Anaconda on a mac. Every time I try to click on the icon to launch, it doesn't open. I looked online for some help and nothing has worked so far. I've tried to update conda via the terminal and I get this error:

```
Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))',),)
```

I have no idea what could have happened as I just used it yesterday and everything was working just fine.

If anyone has experienced this or has any idea on how to fix it, help would be very much appreciated!! Thank you for your time.

--UPDATE---
Surprisingly, if i go to anaconda2 folder and click on the icon, it opens, but when i go the anaconda3 folder (or the icon on my applications folder) it doesn't. Does anyone know the reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: no, it's on a mac

Comment: Looks like it looks for a SSL module but doesn't find it, maybe its a path issue when running from a different folder?

Comment: @J.Doe Were you able to resolve this issue? I get this on an Azure VM (ubuntu) while building a  docker image. The Dockerfile has 'Run conda env update..'.